# dynamically calculate sum of values in an array using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project called "Gold loan management system".[Form fields to insert the ornament name and weight.Total number of ornaments and total weight is calculated automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7rCG.png).I Couldn't calculate the total weight dynamically.Here is my code---

**index.html**

```
<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" name="optioin" ng-model="choice.option" >
<option value="Ring">Ring</option>
<option value="Earings">Earings</option>
 <option value="Chains">Chains</option>
 <option value="Necklaces">Necklaces</option>
 <option value="Bangles">Bangles</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="choice.weight" name=""   placeholder="Enter the weight">gm
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-show="$last"  ng-click="removeChoice()   "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
 <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  </div>    

 </fieldset>
 </form>
 <form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="totnumber">Total Nos:</label>
 <input type="number" ng-model="choices.length" class="form-control"      id="totnumber">
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="totweight">Total Weight:</label>
 <input type="number"   ng-model="total" class="form-control" id="totweight">
 </div>
 </form>
```

**dashboardcntrl.js**

```
  app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
            var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
            $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
             console.log(   $scope. choices.length );

          };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
            var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
            $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
                 console.log(   $scope. choices.length );
          };
        });
```

How can i do that?

Comment: **$last** refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding `#totweight` to a variable you can bind it to a method, like:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="getTotalWeight()" class="form-control" id="totweight" disabled="disabled">
```

Note: Its recommended that the calculated fields are `disabled`

Now in your controller define a function that calculates and returns the total weight, like:

```
$scope.getTotalWeight = function() {
    // calculate total weight and return the value
    // you may want to store it in $scope.total before returning
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the reference from @Vivek Athalye Solved the problem.

**index.html**

```
    <form  class="form-inline form-group">
    <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="optioin" ng-model="choice.option" >
    <option value="Ring">Ring</option>
    <option value="Earings">Earings</option>
    <option value="Chains">Chains</option>
    <option value="Necklaces">Necklaces</option>
    <option value="Bangles">Bangles</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="choice.weight" name="" placeholder="Enter the weight">gm
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-show="$last"  ng-click="removeChoice() "></button>
     <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()"></button>
       </div>   
        </fieldset>
        </form>

               <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="text-left"> Total Numbers:{{ choices.length}}           </p> </div>      <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p  >Total Weight:  {{total(number)}}gm</p>
               </div>
                </div>
```

**dashboardcntrl.js**

```
 $scope.total=function(){
 var tot=0;
 for(i=0;i<$scope.choices.length;i++)
 tot= $scope. choices[i].weight+ tot;
 return tot;
  };
```